# Is my understanding of EOF (end of file) in C correct?

Tags: c, file, pointers, eof, getc

Lets say we have this piece of code:

```
while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
  ...
}
```

This is how i would assume the loop would work, please tell me if it is correct or not/if any mistakes have been made:

1. `getc` reads character from I/O stream `fp`
2. `getc` stores it in the variable `ch`
3. `ch` is tested against `EOF` which is normally equivalent to `-1` (depending on how it is defined for you).
4. When `EOF` is returned it indicates that the `End Of File` indicator for a specific stream has been set. This means that a previous read operation has attempted to read past the end of the file.

**One important question i have:**

In this loop as `getc` gets to the end of the file, does it try to eventually read past the end of the file which causes it to eventually return `EOF`?

Comment: `ch` needs to be an `int` if it's not already.

Comment: lets assume it is in this case.

Comment: It's a common mistake to make it a `char`. See https://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html for details.

Comment: When `getc` returns `EOF`, it does not necessarily mean end of file. `EOF` is also returned if an error occurs, e.g., if the input hardware reported an error.

Comment: @EricPostpischil really? that is certainly very confusing i thought ```EOF``` was just for when a previous read attempt was done which went past end of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. `getc` reads character from I/O stream `fp`

More precisely, `getc` **attempts** to read a character from the `fp` stream.

> 2. `getc` stores it in the variable `ch`

`getc` returns an `int` value, and the assignment `ch = getc(fp)` stores that value in `ch`, if it is representable in the `ch` type. If it is not representable, it is converted in a manner that depends on the `ch` type. To avoid complications with this conversion, `ch` should be `int`.

> 3. `ch` is tested against `EOF` …

Yes, the resulting value of `ch` is compared with `EOF`. This makes the type important: If `getc` returns `EOF` and `ch` is, say, a character type that cannot represent the value of `EOF`, then the conversion will cause a different value to be stored in `ch`, and then it will not compare equal to `EOF`.

> … which is normally equivalent to `-1` (depending on how it is defined for you).

`EOF` may be −1 in many C implementations, but it is normal for it to have any negative `int` value.

> 4. When `EOF` is returned it indicates that the `End Of File` indicator for a specific stream has been set.

No, an `EOF` return indicates that either end-of-file has been reached (and a further read was attempted) or an error occurred. C 2018 7.21.7.5 3 says:

> The `getc` function returns the next character from the input stream pointed to by `stream`. If the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set and getc returns `EOF`. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and `getc` returns `EOF`.

> This means that a previous read operation has attempted to read past the end of the file.

It means either a previous operation or the current operation attempted to read past the end of the file or a previous operation or the current operation encountered an error (and these previous conditions have not been cleared, as by calling `rewind` or `clearerr`).

> In this loop as `getc` gets to the end of the file, does it try to eventually read past the end of the file which causes it to eventually return `EOF`?

If the stream is connected to a file of finite and unchanging size, that loop will eventually attempt to read past the end of file, if nothing in the body of the loop resets the file position, at which point `EOF` will be returned and the loop will exit. However, if the stream is connected to some “infinite” supply of data, such as a pipe, it is possible the loop will never encounter the end of the stream.

Comment: what an amazing answer thank you @EricPostpischil

Answer (score 1):

Once the file stream reaches EOF, the status is supposed to be sticky — all input operations on the file stream will simply report EOF each time they're called.
You can call `clearerr()` to reset the error/EOF status, in which case the input functions will try to read more data until they encounter EOF again.

There was a period when the GNU C Library didn't make the status sticky if the input device was terminal.  That is no longer the case these days.

Answer (score 1):

No, it never tries to read past the end of the file, because the `ch != EOF` condition fails when you get to the end and the loop stops. This happens when the previous iteration read the last character of the file, so you're at the end, not past it.

If you did keep trying to read, it would keep returning `EOF` unless you call `clearerr()`. This can be useful when processing files that get extended (think about how the `tail -f` command works -- it reads until EOF, then keeps checking if the file has grown).

Comment: ```because the ch != EOF condition fails when you get to the end``` but i thought ```EOF``` is returned when a previous read attempt tries to read past end of file?

Comment: No, you're confusing it with the `feof()` function.

Comment: ah i see, so ```EOF``` is returned to indicate end-of-ﬁle, that is, no more input from a stream. And ```feof``` can be used to distinguish if we actually hit ```EOF``` or if a previous read operation has caused our current operation to fail? is that correct?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong for the `feof()` issue

Comment: The difference is that `EOF` is something that's returned when you try to read at the end of the file. `feof()` doesn't try to read anything, so it returns information about the previous read.

Comment: Re “No, it never tries to read past the end of the file”: Calling `getc` when the file position is at the end of file is an attempt to read past the end of the file. That is, the call in which `getc` returns `EOF` (because of end-of-file, not because of error), is an attempt to read past the end.

Comment: I'm distinguishing between reading *at* EOF and reading *past* EOF.